# Typescript CRA with MSW: failed to parse source map

Tags: reactjs, typescript, msw, cra

I have created a Create React App application with typescript template build in, then i installed MSW with npm and created files based on MSW install guide.
It's working perfectly for jest, but for browser when im using start script i got a bunch of warnings that are saying:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/utils/uuid.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '<ROOT_DIR>\node_modules\@mswjs\interceptors\src\utils\uuid.ts' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '<ROOT_DIR>\node_modules\@mswjs\interceptors\src\utils\uuid.ts'
 @ ./node_modules/@mswjs/interceptors/lib/interceptors/fetch/index.js 167:13-40
 @ ./node_modules/msw/lib/esm/index.js 12:0-76 1568:14-28
 @ ./src/mocks/browser.ts 3:0-34 6:22-33
 @ ./src/index.tsx 8:0-41 10:0-12
```

and simmilar...

I couldn't find any answers so Im asking you for help.

Comment: There's an [open issue about this](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1030) on GitHub. Please follow it there. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

*Update:* Issue fixed in [msw 0.38.0](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/releases/tag/v0.38.0).

*Previous answer:*

Are you using `react-scripts 5`?
`Webpack 5` used in that version of `react-scripts` is clashing with `msw` somehow.

You have a couple of options for now:

1. disable source maps by adding a `.env` file in the root of your project containing `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` so that you can keep `react-scripts 5`;
2. downgrade `react-scripts` to `v4`.

More on the [github issue](https://github.com/mswjs/msw/issues/1030) posted by [kettanaito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2754939/kettanaito)

Comment: the most updated and useful answer so far

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disable source maps you could disable the warnings trough [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

1. Add react-app-rewired as dev dependency

   yarn add -D react-app-rewired
2. Rename react-scripts into react-app-rewired in package.json start, test and build scripts
3. Add ignoreWarnings in config-overrides.js at the same level as package.json [as documented in source map loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/source-map-loader#ignoring-warnings).

   ```
   // config-overrides.js
   module.exports = {
     webpack: function (config) {
       return { ...config, ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/] };
     },
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use `react-app-rewired`, downgrade to `react-scripts` `v4` or use `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false` you can check my idea. It is ugly but it works.

Create a script like so:

```js
const { readFileSync, writeFileSync } = require("fs");

const path = "node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/utils.js";
const regex = /.*throw new Error\(`Failed to parse source map from '\${sourceURL}' file: \${error}`\);*/;

const text = readFileSync(path, "utf-8");
const newText = text.replace(regex, `buffer="";sourceURL="";`);
writeFileSync(path, newText, "utf-8");
```

And then add it to your package.json:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node removeSourceMapsWarning.js && react-scripts start"
```

Obviously this code will stop working when `source-map-loader` changes the error message. But I hope we will a real solution for it by then.